# How to cut url down correctly by regex?

Tags: regex, url

May I ask you some question about regex? It will be cool if you could help me to solve an issue. I have tons of urls and I need to find out all unique which has word promo in url.
For instance, I have a bunch urls like that:

```
/promo/vygoda-do-20-na-samsung?from=hb
/promo/antikrizisnaya-rasprodazha-skidki-do-50-mark164615151?from=hb
/promo/antikrizisnaya-rasprodazha-skidki-do-50-mark164615151
```

but I need get like this:

```
/promo/vygoda-do-20-na-samsung
/promo/antikrizisnaya-rasprodazha-skidki-do-50
/promo/antikrizisnaya-rasprodazha-skidki-do-50
```

All I could do it is
https://regex101.com/r/Ot8xzV/1
I have just started my journey to regex and don't have strong knowledge, so, please help me to do it. I'll be very grateful

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @ruohola initially, I wanna filter in GA, then use python

Comment: And what is "GA"?

Comment: google analytics

Comment: Well you can just use the pattern `\/promo\/` to match all urls that that have the text, and then in the Python code use a `set` to remove the duplicates.

Comment: I have to reduce amount of urls in order to download them

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
(.*/promo/[^?]+?)(?:-mark\d+|\?).*
```

Replace with `$1` if you can replace. Capturing group may work for you already.

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/q5sJzK/1).

Comment: what does it mean replace with $1? I didn't understand

Comment: @and_and  See https://regex101.com/r/q5sJzK/1. `$1` stands for the value inside capture group.

Comment: got it but I guess I cannot use this pattern straight in google analytics, can I. My problem is that I have circa 1000000 urls and I cannot download them therefore I have to reduce amount as much as possible

Comment: @and_and Please explain what patterns you *can* use then. It is not quite clear what you can and what you cannot use. Google Analytics uses RE2 regex library, and my regexp is compliant with the library.

Comment: Sorry for misleading, your pattern is work perfectly. I could reduce vast majority of urls but I cannot download though still. It might GA doesn't work correctly since I cannot download the full report. It returns an error 403 forbidden.